# For loop doesn't work properly with value picked from database

Tags: php, mysqli

I designed very simple level script, here the code is:

```
$LEVEL['0'] = 0; //0XP - basic value of main level.
$LEVEL['1'] = 500; //500XP
$LEVEL['2'] = 1100; //+600
$LEVEL['3'] = 1800; //+700
$LEVEL['4'] = 2500; //+800
$LEVEL['5'] = 3300; //+900
$LEVEL['6'] = 4200; //+1000
$LEVEL['7'] = 5200; //+1100
$LEVEL['8'] = 5300; //+1200
$LEVEL['9'] = 6500; //+1300
$LEVEL['10'] = 7800; //+1400 - increase scale rate by 100XP per each tenth level
$LEVEL['11'] = 9200; //+1600
$LEVEL['12'] = 10800; //+1800
$LEVEL['13'] = 12600; //+2000
$LEVEL['14'] = 14600; //+2200
$LEVEL['15'] = 16800; //+2400
$LEVEL['16'] = 19200; //+2600
$LEVEL['17'] = 21800; //+2800
$LEVEL['18'] = 24600; //+3000
$LEVEL['19'] = 27600; //+3200
$LEVEL['20'] = 30800; //+3500

$test = 18000;

for($i = 0; $i < count($LEVEL); $i++){

    if($test > $LEVEL[$i++]){

        $currentLevel = $i++;

    }

}

echo $currentLevel-1;
```

With $test variable it works perfectly but when I pick for example value from SQL database it stops suddenly on tenth iteration.Field has following settings:

```
experience INT(6) UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0
```

I echoed value and it's printed as it should be so for example if it's 10800 it prints 10800 so the right value is picked but it shows not level 11 but 9, ideas?Thanks.

Comment: try making your db column `long or big int` instead of `int`

Comment: I think in this test: if($test > $LEVEL[$i++]) you are incrementing the $i value again so you may miss some levels in your loop

Answer (score 1):

```
$levels = array(
    0,
    500,  //500XP
    1100, //+600
    1800, //+700
    2500, //+800
    // --- all the XPs
);

$test = 18000;

foreach ($levels as $level => $xp) {
    if ($test < $xp) {
        break;
    }
}

echo $level;
```

There is nothing special with the database value.. just use that value instead of `$test`

Answer (score 0):

I'm using value picked from database.Here is chunk of code that generates that weird behaviour

```
//Using loaded user ID, load level of user and skill points.

$queryLevel = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM users_levels WHERE id = '$userId'");
$userLevel = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryLevel);
$userExperience = $userLevel['experience'];
$userPoints = $userLevel['points'];

//Level is 0 if for loop will not find value higher than any given in LEVEL array.

$currentLevel = 0;

for($i = 0; $i < count($LEVEL); $i++){

    if($userExperience > $LEVEL[$i++]){

        $currentLevel = $i++;

    }

}
```

Here is structure of my database table:

```
id INT(50) PRIMARY KEY
experience INT(6) UNSIGNED
points INT(2)
utf8_polish_ci
```

In that table is one row with following values:

```
+----------+----------+----------+ 
|    id    |experience|  points  |
+----------+----------+----------+ 
|    3     |   16200  |     0    |
+----------+----------+----------+
```